# How to create a WSDL from a C# method?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services, wsdl

I have a C# application, and now I need to create a web service from a method that already exist in a windows form app.

Whats the best way to do this ?

Can I generate a wsdl file just for the file or methods that I want to expose ?
And then, how can I put it in the IIS, my application is client-server, so, it isn´t in the IIS yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have code that you have multiple applications accessing, I would split them off into their own dlls and reference it in each application that needs access to it. This is easier to manage.

Create a WCF Service Application Project. This will create the structure needed to host the service via IIS.

IService1 will be your interface. You will create a OperationContract here

```
[OperationContract]
string HelloWorld();
```

In Service1.svc you will add code that you will access your dll

```
public string HelloWorld()
{
    return MyClassFromDll.HelloWorld();
}
```

In your project that will access the service you will add a service reference pointing to the IIS server hosting your service. This will automatically add the needed code to your project.